# Mac Spotify: return to current playlist

Tags: mac, spotify

Let's say I search for an artist using the Spotify search box, pull up an album (served from Spotify's servers), and double-click the first track on the album to start it playing. Great.

Now, I click something else in the left nav (like "Inbox") and switch away from the album.

Spotify will keep playing the whole album I started-- after the 1st track is done, the next track will play, etc.

But how do I get back to the view showing that album, and what track will be next?

(In other words-- in iTunes, I can press command-L for "Current Song" but Spotify doesn't to have that...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the album cover in the lower left corner to get back to the current playlist.

Comment: Great to know! And one of the most un-discoverable bits of UX I've ever seen. :(